# Caching example using ProDataSets in Progress 4gl

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have a particular scenario where I am trying to load a particular static codes table into a prodataset object and then pass this prodataset object around in different progress sessions which we have in our application. The primary purpose of this exercise is to increase performance by caching static data.
I am new to this prodataset concept and would like to get some inputs as to how this caching mechanism using prodataset can be achieved? 
Can somebody outline some high level steps for this or elaborate with an example. Also, we don't want to fill the prodaset object again and again how can the same instance of object be passed between procedures in same session and different session.
Basically we want the different procedures in same or different sessions to access the same prodataset object to increase speed.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Prodatasets are not about caching.  They are all about organizing your data.  Of course you can use that organized data in a caching strategy but you need to have a way to create, manage and access cached data first.

You haven't described what you have in mind there and it seems like maybe you don't have such a strategy so I will address that first.

The class below implements a simple cache of a single field from the sports2000 localDefault table.  I have limited it to caching the currencySymbol for the USA.
With this class in your PROPATH any code can get the currency symbol as often as it likes and it will only read from the database once per minute. There is no need to NEW the class or have USING statements or any of that.  The code using the cached data does not have to be OO either.  Ancient procedural code can access it just fine.

Changing the cached data to a ProDataSet and managing the FILL process should be pretty straight-forward but without an example of the sort of thing you have in mind I can't really do that for you.  You might also want to think about how to organize access to your cached data in a friendly way that will work well with your local coding style.

```
/* cache.cls
 *
 * simple demo of an OpenEdge class to cache db data
 *
 * to loop and use the cached value run this in a test window:
 *
 *   do while true:
 *     display
 *       string( time, "hh:mm:ss" )
 *       cache:currencySign
 *     .
 *     pause 1.
 *   end.
 *
 * in a 2nd window run this to change the currency sign:
 *
 *   find localDefault where country = "usa" exclusive-lock.
 *   update currencySymbol.
 *
 *
 */

class cache:

  define private static property lastRefresh      as datetime  no-undo initial ?  get . set .   /* when was the data read from the db?          */

  define public  static property ttl            as integer   no-undo initial 60 get . set .     /* time to live = 60 seconds                    */

  define public  static property currencySign as character no-undo
    get:

      define variable bh as handle no-undo.

      if lastRefresh = ? or interval( now, lastRefresh, "seconds" ) > ttl then                  /* the data needs to be (re)cached              */
        do:

          create buffer bh for table 'localDefault'.                                            /* the table that we are caching                */

          bh:find-unique( 'where country = "USA"', no-lock ) no-error.                          /* get desired value from the database          */

          if bh:available = yes then
            currencySign = bh:buffer-field( 'currencySymbol' ):buffer-value.                    /* save the cached value                        */
           else
            currencySign = "unknown".

          if valid-handle( bh ) then delete object bh no-error.                                 /* clean up                                     */

          lastRefresh = now.

        end.

      return currencySign.                                                                      /* return the cached data                       */

    end.

    private set .

end class.
```